# Ampscript Error: Object Error not set to an instance of an object

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, content-builder

I am receiving an error on an email template that used to work about a week ago.

When I try to preview it, this is what I get

An error occurred when attempting to compile a Javascript block. See inner exception for detail.
 Script:

```
 var @Country, @Preheader, @SubjectLine, @Text1, @Text2, @langRowsCount, @LanguageLookup

 SET @Country = PersonMailingCountryCode
 SET @LanguageLookup = LookupRows('Translation Table - Email 2', 'Country', @Country)
 SET @langRowsCount = RowCount(@LanguageLookup)

 IF @langRowsCount THEN
 SET @langRow = Row(@LanguageLookup, 1)
 SET @SubjectLine = Field(@langRow, "SubjectLine")
 SET @Preheader = Field(@langRow, "PreHeader")
 SET @Text1 = Field(@langRow, "Text1")
 SET @Text2 = Field(@langRow, "Text2")
 ELSE 
 SET @SubjectLine = 'X'
 SET @Preheader = 'X'
 SET @Text1 = 'X'
 SET @Text1 = 'X'

 ENDIF
```

The strange thing is I have modified this code and the system doesnt seem to recognize it.

I am building this with content builder.

Here is a copy of my current code:

```
<div style="display:none">%%[ 

 var @Country, @Preheader, @SubjectLine, @Text1, @Text2, @langRowsCount, @LanguageLookup

 SET @Country = PersonMailingCountryCode 

 SET @LanguageLookup = LookupRows('Translation Table - Email 2', 'Country', @Country) 

 SET @langRowsCount = RowCount(@LanguageLookup) 

 IF @langRowsCount THEN SET @langRow = Row(@LanguageLookup, 1) 

 SET @SubjectLine = Field(@langRow, "SubjectLine") 

 SET @Preheader = Field(@langRow, "PreHeader") 

 SET @Text1 = Field(@langRow, "Text1") 


 SET @Text2 = Field(@langRow, "Text2") 

 ENDIF ]%%</div>
```

Comment: can you share the opening and closing tags.  If you are using a script tag in AMPscript, you need to make sure to include runat=server and language=Ampscript or the compiler will assume it is javascript and throw an error.

Comment: I used that before but now I am using the code about and deleted the "ELSE" clause. But it still seems to be erroring on code that isnt even in the template anymore

Comment: can you try changing the if statement to `IF @langRowsCount != 0` and check it once

Comment: My issue is that even though I change that in my code, it is still referring the an old script. The bits after X have long been deleted

Comment: have you Apply Template Changes in email?

Comment: try executing the code on the cloudpages/microsite and see if there's any ampscript error.

Comment: I used your above code ('current code' block) with dummy data extensions and it worked as expected without issue (just need to add a '> 0' to your IF statement). It could be a validation error somewhere in your template that is causing issues or potentially another script that is breaking this.  If you could post more of the email, we may be able to better assist.